# Why doesn't this work on Linux but works fine on OSX?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11

I'm trying to do geographical location by IP address for a server mod and it works fine on OSX but on Linux it just outputs nothing. On Mac OSX it works perfectly. Does anything stand out to you in the code that is not linux compatible or that just wouldn't function correctly on Linux? The header HTTPRequest.hpp is open domain and is said to work on Mac, and Linux. Thank you so much for your time!

Header file:

```
//
//  HTTPRequest
//

#ifndef HTTPREQUEST_HPP
#define HTTPREQUEST_HPP

#include <cctype>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

#ifdef _WIN32
#  pragma push_macro("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN")
#  pragma push_macro("NOMINMAX")
#  ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#    define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#  endif
#  ifndef NOMINMAX
#    define NOMINMAX
#  endif
#  include <winsock2.h>
#  if _WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
extern "C" char *_strdup(const char *strSource);
#    define strdup _strdup
#    include <wspiapi.h>
#  endif
#  include <ws2tcpip.h>
#  pragma pop_macro("WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN")
#  pragma pop_macro("NOMINMAX")
#else
#  include <sys/socket.h>
#  include <netinet/in.h>
#  include <netdb.h>
#  include <unistd.h>
#  include <errno.h>
#endif

namespace http
{
    class RequestError final: public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        explicit RequestError(const char* str): std::logic_error(str) {}
        explicit RequestError(const std::string& str): std::logic_error(str) {}
    };

    class ResponseError final: public std::runtime_error
    {
    public:
        explicit ResponseError(const char* str): std::runtime_error(str) {}
        explicit ResponseError(const std::string& str): std::runtime_error(str) {}
    };

    enum class InternetProtocol: std::uint8_t
    {
        V4,
        V6
    };

    inline namespace detail
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        class WinSock final
        {
        public:
            WinSock()
            {
                WSADATA wsaData;
                const auto error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
                if (error != 0)
                    throw std::system_error(error, std::system_category(), "WSAStartup failed");

                if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
                {
                    WSACleanup();
                    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid WinSock version");
                }

                started = true;
            }

            ~WinSock()
            {
                if (started) WSACleanup();
            }

            WinSock(WinSock&& other) noexcept:
                started(other.started)
            {
                other.started = false;
            }

            WinSock& operator=(WinSock&& other) noexcept
            {
                if (&other == this) return *this;
                if (started) WSACleanup();
                started = other.started;
                other.started = false;
                return *this;
            }

        private:
            bool started = false;
        };
#endif

        inline int getLastError() noexcept
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            return WSAGetLastError();
#else
            return errno;
#endif
        }

        constexpr int getAddressFamily(InternetProtocol internetProtocol)
        {
            return (internetProtocol == InternetProtocol::V4) ? AF_INET :
                (internetProtocol == InternetProtocol::V6) ? AF_INET6 :
                throw RequestError("Unsupported protocol");
        }

#ifdef _WIN32
        constexpr auto closeSocket = closesocket;
#else
        constexpr auto closeSocket = close;
#endif

#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(_WIN32)
        constexpr int noSignal = 0;
#else
        constexpr int noSignal = MSG_NOSIGNAL;
#endif

        class Socket final
        {
        public:
#ifdef _WIN32
            using Type = SOCKET;
            static constexpr Type invalid = INVALID_SOCKET;
#else
            using Type = int;
            static constexpr Type invalid = -1;
#endif

            explicit Socket(InternetProtocol internetProtocol):
                endpoint(socket(getAddressFamily(internetProtocol), SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))
            {
                if (endpoint == invalid)
                    throw std::system_error(getLastError(), std::system_category(), "Failed to create socket");

#if defined(__APPLE__)
                const int value = 1;
                if (setsockopt(endpoint, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &value, sizeof(value)) == -1)
                    throw std::system_error(getLastError(), std::system_category(), "Failed to set socket option");
#endif
            }

            ~Socket()
            {
                if (endpoint != invalid) closeSocket(endpoint);
            }

            Socket(Socket&& other) noexcept:
                endpoint(other.endpoint)
            {
                other.endpoint = invalid;
            }

            Socket& operator=(Socket&& other) noexcept
            {
                if (&other == this) return *this;
                if (endpoint != invalid) closeSocket(endpoint);
                endpoint = other.endpoint;
                other.endpoint = invalid;
                return *this;
            }

            void connect(const struct sockaddr* address, socklen_t addressSize)
            {
                auto result = ::connect(endpoint, address, addressSize);

#ifdef _WIN32
                while (result == -1 && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEINTR)
                    result = ::connect(endpoint, address, addressSize);
#else
                while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                    result = ::connect(endpoint, address, addressSize);
#endif

                if (result == -1)
                    throw std::system_error(getLastError(), std::system_category(), "Failed to connect");
            }

            size_t send(const void* buffer, size_t length, int flags)
            {
#ifdef _WIN32
                auto result = ::send(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer),
                                     static_cast<int>(length), flags);

                while (result == -1 && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEINTR)
                    result = ::send(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer),
                                    static_cast<int>(length), flags);

#else
                auto result = ::send(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer),
                                     length, flags);

                while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                    result = ::send(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer),
                                    length, flags);
#endif
                if (result == -1)
                    throw std::system_error(getLastError(), std::system_category(), "Failed to send data");

                return static_cast<size_t>(result);
            }

            size_t recv(void* buffer, size_t length, int flags)
            {
#ifdef _WIN32
                auto result = ::recv(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer),
                                     static_cast<int>(length), flags);

                while (result == -1 && WSAGetLastError() == WSAEINTR)
                    result = ::recv(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer),
                                    static_cast<int>(length), flags);
#else
                auto result = ::recv(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer),
                                     length, flags);

                while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                    result = ::recv(endpoint, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer),
                                    length, flags);
#endif
                if (result == -1)
                    throw std::system_error(getLastError(), std::system_category(), "Failed to read data");

                return static_cast<size_t>(result);
            }

            operator Type() const noexcept { return endpoint; }

        private:
            Type endpoint = invalid;
        };
    }

    inline std::string urlEncode(const std::string& str)
    {
        constexpr char hexChars[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

        std::string result;

        for (auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); ++i)
        {
            const std::uint8_t cp = *i & 0xFF;

            if ((cp >= 0x30 && cp <= 0x39) || // 0-9
                (cp >= 0x41 && cp <= 0x5A) || // A-Z
                (cp >= 0x61 && cp <= 0x7A) || // a-z
                cp == 0x2D || cp == 0x2E || cp == 0x5F) // - . _
                result += static_cast<char>(cp);
            else if (cp <= 0x7F) // length = 1
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
            else if ((cp >> 5) == 0x06) // length = 2
            {
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
                if (++i == str.end()) break;
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
            }
            else if ((cp >> 4) == 0x0E) // length = 3
            {
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
                if (++i == str.end()) break;
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
                if (++i == str.end()) break;
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
            }
            else if ((cp >> 3) == 0x1E) // length = 4
            {
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
                if (++i == str.end()) break;
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
                if (++i == str.end()) break;
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
                if (++i == str.end()) break;
                result += std::string("%") + hexChars[(*i & 0xF0) >> 4] + hexChars[*i & 0x0F];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    struct Response final
    {
        enum Status
        {
            Continue = 100,
            SwitchingProtocol = 101,
            Processing = 102,
            EarlyHints = 103,

            Ok = 200,
            Created = 201,
            Accepted = 202,
            NonAuthoritativeInformation = 203,
            NoContent = 204,
            ResetContent = 205,
            PartialContent = 206,
            MultiStatus = 207,
            AlreadyReported = 208,
            ImUsed = 226,

            MultipleChoice = 300,
            MovedPermanently = 301,
            Found = 302,
            SeeOther = 303,
            NotModified = 304,
            UseProxy = 305,
            TemporaryRedirect = 307,
            PermanentRedirect = 308,

            BadRequest = 400,
            Unauthorized = 401,
            PaymentRequired = 402,
            Forbidden = 403,
            NotFound = 404,
            MethodNotAllowed = 405,
            NotAcceptable = 406,
            ProxyAuthenticationRequired = 407,
            RequestTimeout = 408,
            Conflict = 409,
            Gone = 410,
            LengthRequired = 411,
            PreconditionFailed = 412,
            PayloadTooLarge = 413,
            UriTooLong = 414,
            UnsupportedMediaType = 415,
            RangeNotSatisfiable = 416,
            ExpectationFailed = 417,
            ImaTeapot = 418,
            MisdirectedRequest = 421,
            UnprocessableEntity = 422,
            Locked = 423,
            FailedDependency = 424,
            TooEarly = 425,
            UpgradeRequired = 426,
            PreconditionRequired = 428,
            TooManyRequests = 429,
            RequestHeaderFieldsTooLarge = 431,
            UnavailableForLegalReasons = 451,

            InternalServerError = 500,
            NotImplemented = 501,
            BadGateway = 502,
            ServiceUnavailable = 503,
            GatewayTimeout = 504,
            HttpVersionNotSupported = 505,
            VariantAlsoNegotiates = 506,
            InsufficientStorage = 507,
            LoopDetected = 508,
            NotExtended = 510,
            NetworkAuthenticationRequired = 511
        };

        int status = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> headers;
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> body;
    };

    class Request final
    {
    public:
        explicit Request(const std::string& url,
                         InternetProtocol protocol = InternetProtocol::V4):
            internetProtocol(protocol)
        {
            const auto schemeEndPosition = url.find("://");

            if (schemeEndPosition != std::string::npos)
            {
                scheme = url.substr(0, schemeEndPosition);
                path = url.substr(schemeEndPosition + 3);
            }
            else
            {
                scheme = "http";
                path = url;
            }

            const auto fragmentPosition = path.find('#');

            // remove the fragment part
            if (fragmentPosition != std::string::npos)
                path.resize(fragmentPosition);

            const auto pathPosition = path.find('/');

            if (pathPosition == std::string::npos)
            {
                domain = path;
                path = "/";
            }
            else
            {
                domain = path.substr(0, pathPosition);
                path = path.substr(pathPosition);
            }

            const auto portPosition = domain.find(':');

            if (portPosition != std::string::npos)
            {
                port = domain.substr(portPosition + 1);
                domain.resize(portPosition);
            }
            else
                port = "80";
        }

        Response send(const std::string& method,
                      const std::map<std::string, std::string>& parameters,
                      const std::vector<std::string>& headers = {})
        {
            std::string body;
            bool first = true;

            for (const auto& parameter : parameters)
            {
                if (!first) body += "&";
                first = false;

                body += urlEncode(parameter.first) + "=" + urlEncode(parameter.second);
            }

            return send(method, body, headers);
        }

        Response send(const std::string& method = "GET",
                      const std::string& body = "",
                      const std::vector<std::string>& headers = {})
        {
            return send(method,
                        std::vector<uint8_t>(body.begin(), body.end()),
                        headers);
        }

        Response send(const std::string& method,
                      const std::vector<uint8_t>& body,
                      const std::vector<std::string>& headers)
        {
            if (scheme != "http")
                throw RequestError("Only HTTP scheme is supported");

            addrinfo hints = {};
            hints.ai_family = getAddressFamily(internetProtocol);
            hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

            addrinfo* info;
            if (getaddrinfo(domain.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &info) != 0)
                throw std::system_error(getLastError(), std::system_category(), "Failed to get address info of " + domain);

            std::unique_ptr<addrinfo, decltype(&freeaddrinfo)> addressInfo(info, freeaddrinfo);

            std::string headerData = method + " " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";

            for (const std::string& header : headers)
                headerData += header + "\r\n";

            headerData += "Host: " + domain + "\r\n"
                "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(body.size()) + "\r\n"
                "\r\n";

            std::vector<uint8_t> requestData(headerData.begin(), headerData.end());
            requestData.insert(requestData.end(), body.begin(), body.end());

            Socket socket(internetProtocol);

            // take the first address from the list
            socket.connect(addressInfo->ai_addr, static_cast<socklen_t>(addressInfo->ai_addrlen));

            auto remaining = requestData.size();
            auto sendData = requestData.data();

            // send the request
            while (remaining > 0)
            {
                const auto size = socket.send(sendData, remaining, noSignal);
                remaining -= size;
                sendData += size;
            }

            std::uint8_t tempBuffer[4096];
            constexpr std::uint8_t crlf[] = {'\r', '\n'};
            Response response;
            std::vector<std::uint8_t> responseData;
            bool firstLine = true;
            bool parsedHeaders = false;
            bool contentLengthReceived = false;
            unsigned long contentLength = 0;
            bool chunkedResponse = false;
            std::size_t expectedChunkSize = 0;
            bool removeCrlfAfterChunk = false;

            // read the response
            for (;;)
            {
                const auto size = socket.recv(tempBuffer, sizeof(tempBuffer), noSignal);

                if (size == 0)
                    break; // disconnected

                responseData.insert(responseData.end(), tempBuffer, tempBuffer + size);

                if (!parsedHeaders)
                    for (;;)
                    {
                        const auto i = std::search(responseData.begin(), responseData.end(), std::begin(crlf), std::end(crlf));

                        // didn't find a newline
                        if (i == responseData.end()) break;

                        const std::string line(responseData.begin(), i);
                        responseData.erase(responseData.begin(), i + 2);

                        // empty line indicates the end of the header section
                        if (line.empty())
                        {
                            parsedHeaders = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (firstLine) // first line
                        {
                            firstLine = false;

                            std::string::size_type lastPos = 0;
                            const auto length = line.length();
                            std::vector<std::string> parts;

                            // tokenize first line
                            while (lastPos < length + 1)
                            {
                                auto pos = line.find(' ', lastPos);
                                if (pos == std::string::npos) pos = length;

                                if (pos != lastPos)
                                    parts.emplace_back(line.data() + lastPos,
                                                       static_cast<std::vector<std::string>::size_type>(pos) - lastPos);

                                lastPos = pos + 1;
                            }

                            if (parts.size() >= 2)
                                response.status = std::stoi(parts[1]);
                        }
                        else // headers
                        {
                            response.headers.push_back(line);

                            const auto pos = line.find(':');

                            if (pos != std::string::npos)
                            {
                                std::string headerName = line.substr(0, pos);
                                std::string headerValue = line.substr(pos + 1);

                                // ltrim
                                headerValue.erase(headerValue.begin(),
                                                  std::find_if(headerValue.begin(), headerValue.end(),
                                                               [](int c) {return !std::isspace(c);}));

                                // rtrim
                                headerValue.erase(std::find_if(headerValue.rbegin(), headerValue.rend(),
                                                               [](int c) {return !std::isspace(c);}).base(),
                                                  headerValue.end());

                                if (headerName == "Content-Length")
                                {
                                    contentLength = std::stoul(headerValue);
                                    contentLengthReceived = true;
                                    response.body.reserve(contentLength);
                                }
                                else if (headerName == "Transfer-Encoding")
                                {
                                    if (headerValue == "chunked")
                                        chunkedResponse = true;
                                    else
                                        throw ResponseError("Unsupported transfer encoding: " + headerValue);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                if (parsedHeaders)
                {
                    // Content-Length must be ignored if Transfer-Encoding is received
                    if (chunkedResponse)
                    {
                        bool dataReceived = false;
                        for (;;)
                        {
                            if (expectedChunkSize > 0)
                            {
                                const auto toWrite = std::min(expectedChunkSize, responseData.size());
                                response.body.insert(response.body.end(), responseData.begin(), responseData.begin() + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(toWrite));
                                responseData.erase(responseData.begin(), responseData.begin() + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(toWrite));
                                expectedChunkSize -= toWrite;

                                if (expectedChunkSize == 0) removeCrlfAfterChunk = true;
                                if (responseData.empty()) break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (removeCrlfAfterChunk)
                                {
                                    if (responseData.size() >= 2)
                                    {
                                        removeCrlfAfterChunk = false;
                                        responseData.erase(responseData.begin(), responseData.begin() + 2);
                                    }
                                    else break;
                                }

                                const auto i = std::search(responseData.begin(), responseData.end(), std::begin(crlf), std::end(crlf));

                                if (i == responseData.end()) break;

                                const std::string line(responseData.begin(), i);
                                responseData.erase(responseData.begin(), i + 2);

                                expectedChunkSize = std::stoul(line, nullptr, 16);

                                if (expectedChunkSize == 0)
                                {
                                    dataReceived = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (dataReceived)
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.body.insert(response.body.end(), responseData.begin(), responseData.end());
                        responseData.clear();

                        // got the whole content
                        if (contentLengthReceived && response.body.size() >= contentLength)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return response;
        }

    private:
#ifdef _WIN32
        WinSock winSock;
#endif
        InternetProtocol internetProtocol;
        std::string scheme;
        std::string domain;
        std::string port;
        std::string path;
    };
}

#endif
```

C++ file

```
    void ReplaceStringInPlace(std::string& subject, const std::string& search, const std::string& replace) {
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
            subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
            pos += replace.length();
        }
    }

    char* DeleteLast2Chars(char* name)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(name[i] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
        }
        name[i-2] = '\0';
        return name;
    }

             if(HTTP_geolocation) {
                try
                {
                    //pull info
                    defformatstring(r_str)("%s%s%s", "http://ip-api.com/line/", ip, "?fields=city,regionName,country");
                    http::Request req(r_str);
                    const http::Response res = req.send("GET");
                    const char* a = std::string(res.body.begin(), res.body.end()).c_str();
                    
                    //cleanup and output
                    std::string s = a;
                    ReplaceStringInPlace(s, "\n", " > ");
                    DeleteLast2Chars((char *)a);
                    defformatstring(msg)("\f0%s \f7connected from \f6%s", colorname(ci), a);
                    out(ECHO_SERV,"%s", msg);
                    defformatstring(cmsg)("%s connected from %s", colorname(ci), a);
                    out(ECHO_CONSOLE,"%s", cmsg);
                }
                catch (const std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << "[ERROR]: HTTP geolocation failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing you can and should debug yourself, either in a debugger or by inserting temporary print/log/whatever statements to trace which code gets executed both on the working system and on the non-working system.  Eventually you will find the point at which the working and non-working programs' code-paths diverge, and it is that point where your problem lies.

Comment: The `std::string` in `const char* a = std::string(res.body.begin(), res.body.end()).c_str();` is a temporary variable. It's only around until the end of the line. It goes out of scope and dies, taking it's internal buffer with it, before you can use the pointer to its internal buffer. The only reason it works on OSX is bad luck.

Comment: @user4581301 How can I prevent it from dying?

Comment: Don't use `a` go directly to `s`.

Comment: The next line assigns the pointer to `s`, so rather than constructing a temporary, construct `s`. Then get the buffer out of `s`.

Comment: Nope It's not that easy. `ReplaceStringInPlace(s, "\n", " > ");` modifies `s`, potentially wrecking `a`, and then if not `DeleteLast2Chars((char *)a);` modifying `a` wrecks `s`.

Comment: If possible try to work exclusively on `s` and get the buffer out of it when you call to make `msg` and `cmsg`. `DeleteLast2Chars` could be [`s.pop_back(); s.pop_back();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) if it doesn't do anything more than simply remove the last two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you, totally untested ofcourse.

```
//pull info
defformatstring(r_str)("%s%s%s", "http://ip-api.com/line/", ip, "?fields=city,regionName,country");
http::Request req(r_str);
const http::Response res = req.send("GET");
                
//cleanup and output
std::string s(res.body.begin(), res.body.end());
ReplaceStringInPlace(s, "\n", " > "); // using .find and .replace?
s.erase(s.length()-2, 2); //DeleteLast2Chars((char *)a);
defformatstring(msg)("\f0%s \f7connected from \f6%s", colorname(ci), s.c_str());
out(ECHO_SERV,"%s", msg);
defformatstring(cmsg)("%s connected from %s", colorname(ci), s.c_str());
out(ECHO_CONSOLE,"%s", cmsg);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this and got some errors. It won't let me post here because there is a comment length limit, so here's the pastebin'd errors: https://pastebin.com/r7tTaGpH

Comment: @GeorgeScott my .str() should have been .c_str() as it says in the error message.

Comment: You're a god lol it works. Thank you so much! This syntax of this part confused me "std::string s(res.body.begin(), res.body.end());" I was writing it like "std::string s =(res.body.begin(), res.body.end());"

Comment: @GeorgeScott it calls the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong:

- The `a` pointer is dangling since the `std::string` object that managed that memory ended its lifetime.
- But after that, another `std::string` object called `s` is created from the `a` one. Why not keep the original object instead?
- The constness of the `a` pointer is cast away to pass it to another function which looks like modify its contents.

Then there are functions we cannot see, like `ReplaceStringInPlace`, so we can only guess if those are correct. If they aren't, it may still produce undefined behavior that breaks it.

The program may appear to work in macOS, but that is just by chance.